# OdbcConnection returning Chinese Characters as "?"

Tags: c#, oracle, odbc

I have an Oracle database that stores some data values in Simplified Chinese. I have created an ASP.net MVC C# webpage that is supposed to display this information. I am using a `OdbcConnection` in order to retrieve the data, however when I run my `da.Fill(t)` command the values return as "?"

```
        OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = select;

        OdbcConnection SqlConn = new OdbcConnection("Driver={Oracle in instantclient_11_2};Dbq=Database;Uid=Username;pwd=password;");
        DataTable t = new DataTable();
        cmd.Connection = SqlConn;

        SqlConn.Open();
        OdbcDataAdapter da = new OdbcDataAdapter(cmd);
        SqlConn.Close();
        da.Fill(t);
        return t;
```

`t` has the data but everything that is supposed to be the Chinese characters is just a series of "?????"

Comment: Make sure your page is served as UTF8.

Comment: What is your database character set?  What is your client `nls_lang`?

Comment: The page displays other hardcoded Chinese characters fine, but its just the data connection that is returning the "?"s

Comment: `NLS_LANGUAGE = AMERICAN`  `NLS_CHARACTERSET = AL32UTF8` on my oracle database

Comment: @LukeKonecki, that was not asked, it was "What is your client `nls_lang`?"

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Problems with character set are quite common, let me try to give some general notes.

In principle you have to consider **four** different character set settings.

#### 1 and 2: `NLS_CHARACTERSET` and `NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET`

Example: `AL32UTF8`

They are defined **only** on your database, you can interrogate them with

```
    SELECT * 
    FROM V$NLS_PARAMETERS 
    WHERE PARAMETER IN ('NLS_CHARACTERSET', 'NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET');
```

These settings define which characters (in which format) can be stored in your database - no more, no less. It requires some effort (see [Character Set Migration](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/NLSPG/ch11charsetmig.htm) and/or [Oracle Database Migration Assistant for Unicode](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E71288_01/DUMAG/toc.htm)) if you have to change it on existing database.

You can find Oracle supported character set at [Character Sets](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/nlspg/appendix-A-locale-data.html#GUID-344E34CA-DD16-4979-8CF1-6D0A7AEBAA4A).

#### 3: `NLS_LANG`

Example: `AMERICAN_AMERICA.AL32UTF8`

This value is defined **only** on your client. NLS_LANG has nothing to do with the ability to store characters in a database. It is used to let Oracle know what character set you are using on the client side. When you set NLS_LANG value (for example to AL32UTF8) then you just tell the Oracle database "my client uses character set AL32UTF8" - it does not necessarily mean that your client is really using AL32UTF8! (see below #4)

NLS_LANG can be defined by environment variable `NLS_LANG` or by Windows Registry at `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\ORACLE\KEY_%ORACLE_HOME_NAME%\NLS_LANG` (for 32 bit), resp. `HKLM\SOFTWARE\ORACLE\KEY_%ORACLE_HOME_NAME%\NLS_LANG` (for 64 bit). Depending on your application there might be other ways to specify NLS_LANG, but let's stick to the basics. If NLS_LANG value is not provided then Oracle defaults it to `AMERICAN_AMERICA.US7ASCII`

Format of NLS_LANG is `NLS_LANG=language_territory.charset`. The {*charset*} part of NLS_LANG is **not** shown in any system table or view. All components of the NLS_LANG definition are optional, so following definitions are all valid: `NLS_LANG=.WE8ISO8859P1`, `NLS_LANG=_GERMANY`, `NLS_LANG=AMERICAN`, `NLS_LANG=ITALIAN_.WE8MSWIN1252`, `NLS_LANG=_BELGIUM.US7ASCII`.

As stated above the {charset} part of `NLS_LANG` is not available in database at any system table/view or any function. Strictly speaking this is true, however you can run this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT CLIENT_CHARSET
FROM V$SESSION_CONNECT_INFO
WHERE (SID, SERIAL#) = (SELECT SID, SERIAL# FROM v$SESSION WHERE AUDSID = USERENV('SESSIONID'));
```

It should return character set from your current `NLS_LANG` setting - however based on my experience the value is often NULL or `Unknown`, i.e. not reliable.

Find more very useful information here: [NLS_LANG FAQ](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/products/globalization/nls-lang-099431.html)

Note, some technologies do not utilize `NLS_LANG`, settings there do not have any effect, for example:

- ODP.NET Managed Driver is not `NLS_LANG` sensitive. It is only .NET locale sensitive. (see [Data Provider for .NET Developer's Guide](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E51173_01/win.122/e17732/featGlobal.htm#ODPNT437))
- OraOLEDB (from Oracle) always use UTF-16 (see [OraOLEDB Provider Specific Features](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/OLEDB/using.htm#OLEDB210))
- Java based JDBC (for example SQL Developer) has its own methods to deal with character sets (see [Database JDBC Developer's Guide - Globalization Support](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/JJDBC/global.htm#JJDBC28643) for further details)

#### 4: The "real" character set of your terminal, your application or the encoding of `.sql` files

Example: `UTF-8`

If you work with a terminal program (i.e. SQL*plus or isql) you can interrogate the code page with command `chcp`, on Unix/Linux the equivalent is `locale charmap` or `echo $LANG`. You can get a list of all Windows code pages identifiers from here: [Code Page Identifiers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/intl/code-page-identifiers). Note, for UTF-8 (`chcp 65001`) there are some issues, see [this discussion](https://community.oracle.com/thread/600575).

If you work with `.sql` files and an editor like TOAD or SQL-Developer you have to check the save options. Usually you can choose values like `UTF-8`, `ANSI`, `ISO-8859-1`, etc.
`ANSI` means the Windows ANSI codepage, typically `CP1252`, you can check in your Registry at `HKLM\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\Nls\CodePage\ACP` or here: [National Language Support (NLS) API Reference](https://www.microsoft.com/resources/msdn/goglobal/default.mspx)

*[Microsoft removed this reference, take it form web-archive [National Language Support (NLS) API Reference]
[11](https://web.archive.org/web/20171015144140/https://www.microsoft.com/resources/msdn/goglobal/default.mspx)]*

#### How to set all these values?

The most important point is to match `NLS_LANG` and your "real" character set of your terminal, resp. application or the encoding of your `.sql` files

Some common pairs are:

- CP850 -> `WE8PC850`
- CP1252 or ANSI (in case of "Western" PC) -> `WE8MSWIN1252`
- ISO-8859-1 -> `WE8ISO8859P1`
- ISO-8859-15 -> `WE8ISO8859P15`
- UTF-8 -> `AL32UTF8`

Or run this query to get some more:

```
SELECT VALUE AS ORACLE_CHARSET, UTL_I18N.MAP_CHARSET(VALUE) AS IANA_NAME
FROM V$NLS_VALID_VALUES
WHERE PARAMETER = 'CHARACTERSET';
```

Some technologies make you life easier, e.g. ODP.NET (unmanged driver) or ODBC driver from Oracle automatically inherits the character set from `NLS_LANG` value, so condition from above is always true.

**Is it required to set client NLS_LANG value equal to database `NLS_CHARACTERSET` value?**

No, not necessarily! For example, if you have the **database** character set `NLS_CHARACTERSET=AL32UTF8` and the **client** character set `NLS_LANG=.ZHS32GB18030` then it will work without any problem (provided your client really uses GB18030), although these character sets are completely different. [GB18030](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GB_18030) is a character set commonly used for Chinese, like `UTF-8` it supports all Unicode characters.

If you have, for example `NLS_CHARACTERSET=AL32UTF8` and `NLS_LANG=.WE8ISO8859P1` it will also work (again, provided your client really uses ISO-8859-P1). However, the database may store characters which your client is not able to display, instead the client will display a placeholder (e.g. `¿`).

Anyway, it is beneficial to have matching NLS_LANG and NLS_CHARACTERSET values, if suitable. If they are equal you can be sure that any character which may be stored in database can also be displayed and any character you enter in your terminal or write in your .sql file can also be stored in database and is not substituted by placeholder.

#### Supplement

So many times you can read advise like "The NLS_LANG character set must be the same as your database character set" (also here on SO). This is simply not true and a popular myth!

See also [Should the NLS_LANG Setting Match the Database Character Set?](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/nlspg/setting-up-globalization-support-environment.html#GUID-372A5104-DC0A-41CA-B449-6AEC93F09C2E)

> The `NLS_LANG` character set should reflect the setting of the operating system character set of the client. For example, if the database character set is `AL32UTF8` and the client is running on a Windows operating system, then you should not set `AL32UTF8` as the client character set in the `NLS_LANG` parameter because there are no UTF-8 WIN32 clients. Instead, the `NLS_LANG` setting should reflect the code page of the client. For example, on an English Windows client, the code page is 1252. An appropriate setting for `NLS_LANG` is `AMERICAN_AMERICA.WE8MSWIN1252`.
>
> Setting `NLS_LANG` correctly enables proper conversion from the client operating system character set to the database character set. When these settings are the same, Oracle Database assumes that the data being sent or received is encoded in the same character set as the database character set, so character set validation or conversion may not be performed. This can lead to corrupt data if the client code page and the database character set are different and conversions are necessary.

However, statement "*there are no UTF-8 WIN32 clients*" is certainly outdated nowadays!

Here is the proof:

```
C:\>set NLS_LANG=.AL32UTF8

C:\>sqlplus ...

SQL> SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
SQL> DECLARE
  2  CharSet VARCHAR2(20);
  3  BEGIN
  4     SELECT VALUE INTO Charset FROM nls_database_parameters WHERE parameter = 'NLS_CHARACTERSET';
  5     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Database NLS_CHARACTERSET is '||Charset);
  6     IF UNISTR('\20AC') = '€' THEN
  7             DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ( '"€" is equal to U+20AC' );
  8     ELSE
  9             DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ( '"€" is not the same as U+20AC' );
 10     END IF;
 11  END;
 12  /

Database NLS_CHARACTERSET is AL32UTF8
"€" is not the same as U+20AC

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Both, client and database character sets are `AL32UTF8`, however the characters do not match. The reason is, my `cmd.exe` and thus also SQL*Plus use Windows CP1252. Therefore I must set NLS_LANG accordingly:

```
C:\>chcp
Active code page: 1252

C:\>set NLS_LANG=.WE8MSWIN1252

C:\>sqlplus ...

SQL> SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
SQL> DECLARE
  2  CharSet VARCHAR2(20);
  3  BEGIN
  4     SELECT VALUE INTO Charset FROM nls_database_parameters WHERE parameter = 'NLS_CHARACTERSET';
  5     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Database NLS_CHARACTERSET is '||Charset);
  6     IF UNISTR('\20AC') = '€' THEN
  7             DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ( '"€" is equal to U+20AC' );
  8     ELSE
  9             DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ( '"€" is not the same as U+20AC' );
 10     END IF;
 11  END;
 12  /

Database NLS_CHARACTERSET is AL32UTF8
"€" is equal to U+20AC

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Also consider this example:

```
CREATE TABLE ARABIC_LANGUAGE (
    LANG_CHAR VARCHAR2(20), 
    LANG_NCHAR NVARCHAR2(20));

INSERT INTO ARABIC_LANGUAGE VALUES ('العربية', 'العربية');
```

You would need to set two different values for `NLS_LANG` for a single statement - which is not possible.

See also [If we have US7ASCII characterset why does it let us store non-ascii characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47039666/if-we-have-us7ascii-characterset-why-does-it-let-us-store-non-ascii-characters/47051107#47051107) or [difference between NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET and NLS_CHARACTERSET for Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36710360/difference-between-nls-nchar-characterset-and-nls-characterset-for-oracle/36712457#36712457)

Comment: Thanks for the help. I was able to set the NLS_LANG environment variable on my webserver to `AMERICAN_AMERICA.AL32UTF8` and that fixed the issue.