# Oracle enconding inverted interrogation characters

Tags: oracle

I do find a problem with enconding of characters into Oracle

They are two inverted interrogation characters coming from imported data.

How can i search for two inverted characters into Oracle so i can see how many lines have this problem ?

Comment: The inverted characters are characters that your database or client does not know how to display.  Look in the source data and check your NLS settings for the database

Comment: And the NLS settings for the session you're querying from when you see those, including your NLS_LANG environment variable.

Comment: You can use the dump function to show the byte values of a string. This way you can figure out what is actually stored in the table.

select dump(column) from table;

Comment: `¿` is a regular (and fairly common) character in Spanish. Shall we assume you don't handle Spanish texts?

Comment: Yes i am on Brasil and this database have imported data from Mysql and does not have the same encoding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume by "inverted interrogation character" you mean character `¿`.

There are two possibilities:

1. Character `¿` is actually stored in your database, because your database character set (check with `SELECT * FROM V$NLS_PARAMETERS WHERE PARAMETER LIKE '%CHARACTERSET'`) is not capable to support special characters you tried to import.

   You can find affected rows with `SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(COL_NAME, '¿');`
2. Your client (e.g. SQL*Plus) is not able to **display** the special character and substitute those by placeholder `¿`. In this case set your `NLS_LANG` value properly, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33783902/odbcconnection-returning-chinese-characters-as/33790600#33790600) for more details.

Unfortunately you did not tell us how you imported your data nor any of your characters sets. Thus I cannot provide you a guideline to set `NLS_LANG` properly.

Comment: It is a mysql import i did not have much details but using SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(COL_NAME, '¿'); i can track how many records are afeccted and maybe to fix

Comment: Can i use REGEXP_LIKE to find accents ? something like NOT (A-Z a-z)
SELECT * FROM clients WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(name, '[A-Z] ');