# Special Characters not getting displayed in Oracle tables

Tags: oracle

I have data which contains special characters like à ç è etc..

I am trying to insert the data into tables  having these characters. Data gets inserted without any issues but these characters are replaced with  with ?/?? when stored in tables

How should I resolve this issue?I want to store  these characters in my tables.

Is it related to NLS parameters?
 Currently the NLS characterset is having AL32UTF8 as seen from V$Nls_parameters table.

Is there any specific table/column to be checked ? Or is it something at the database settings ?

Kindly advise.

Thank in advance

Comment: DataType for the column must be NVARCHAR

Comment: @Jaydipj: I don't believe that's accurate. I've had VARCHAR2 fields defined and working with those characters with no issue before. It's about the character set and defined NLS_LANG, not your data type ...

Comment: @sqlpractice: Show your NLS_LANG parameter from the client when doing the insert.

Comment: It is Varchar2(50 char). I am able to see the characters in one database but not in other.Table specification is same in both the databases

Comment: @sqlpractice: also, can you insert a single character: `à` .. and then `select col, dump(col) from yourtable;`  ??

Comment: @Ditto when I tried select àctive from dual. It replace à with ? Also where can I see NLS_LANG ..I checked NLS_LANGUAGE it is American. LANG variable  in export is defined as en_US.UTF-8

Comment: Where do you see these ?? ? I've tried to select data from a table using sqlplus from ms-dos command prompt on a French OS and I see the `à` correctly but doing the same thing from an English OS displays `ÔÇª`

Comment: @StephaneM I am using sqplus from putty.language is American. Both the database have same language but it is generating ? in one server only

Answer (score 1):

From the comments: It is not required that column must be `NVARCHAR` (resp. `NVARCHAR2`), because your database character set is `AL32UTF8` which supports any Unicode character.

Set your `NLS_LANG` variable to `AMERICAN_AMERICA.AL32UTF8` before you launch your SQL*Plus. You may change the language and/or territory to your own preferences.

Ensure you select a font which is able to display the special characters.

Note, client character set `AL32UTF8` is determined by your local `LANG` variable (i.e. `en_US.UTF-8`), **not** by the database character set.

Check also this answer for more information: [OdbcConnection returning Chinese Characters as "?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33783902/odbcconnection-returning-chinese-characters-as/33790600#33790600)

Comment: thanks for your answer.So setting NLS_LANG would be session specific? I mean will I have to do this every time I want to see the data with a new sqlplus session? If yes, then is there any permanent solution.. Also how can we see the current NLS_LANG variable value

Comment: `NLS_LANG` is set for your client, it is not session specific, i.e. you cannot change it inside a session. You can set your `NLS_LANG` environment variable permanently. In order to change the encoding of your `cmd.exe`, resp. SQL*Plus follow this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388490/unicode-characters-in-windows-command-line-how/33475373#33475373

Comment: I am connecting to the server using putty.exe and then connecting sqlplus on the server and I cannot change the registry on that server..Also how can I see the current value of NLS_LANG

Comment: Check settings of Putty there you can set Utf8. Run "echo $NLS_LANG"

Comment: My putty settings already have UTF-8 .I got nothing when I tried echo $NLS_LANG ..I got blank row  even on the server which is storing the correct characters.

Comment: Google for "how to set environment variable in Linux"!

Comment: Thank you all for your replies.Issue is resolved now.The problem was with sqlplus settings.If I see the same data using SQLDeveloper the chars are visible as expected..It has something to do specific to SQLPLUS..please enlighten if anyone has more information on this as what specific settings ?why does it happen