# difference between NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET and NLS_CHARACTERSET for Oracle

Tags: oracle, character-encoding, ascii, utf, varchar2

I would like to know the difference between
`NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET` and `NLS_CHARACTERSET` settings in Oracle?

From my understanding, `NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET` is for `NVARCHAR` data types
and for `NLS_CHARACTERSET`  would be for VARCHAR2 data types.

I tried to test this on my development server which my current settings for `CHARACTERSET` are as the following :

```
PARAMETER                      VALUE
------------------------------ ----------------------------------------
NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET         AL16UTF16
NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS         .,
NLS_CHARACTERSET               US7ASCII
```

Then I inserted some Chinese character values into the database. I inserted the characters into a table called `data_<seqno>` and updated the column for `ADDRESS` and `ADDRESS_2` which are `VARCHAR2` columns. Right from my understanding with the current setting for `NLS_CHARACTERSET` `US7ASCII`, Chinese characters should not be supported but it is still showing in the database. Does `NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET` take precedence over this?

Thank You.

Comment: You should not copy screenshots. Copy/paste the text from SQL Plus and format the code

Comment: okay noted. thanks for pointing out :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In general all your points are correct. `NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET` defines the character set for `NVARCHAR2`, et. al. columns whereas `NLS_CHARACTERSET` is used for `VARCHAR2`.

> Why is it possible that you see Chinese characters with `US7ASCII`?

The reason is, your database character set and your client character set (i.e. see `NLS_LANG` value) are both `US7ASCII`. Your database uses `US7ASCII` and it "thinks" also the client sends data using `US7ASCII`. Thus it does not make any conversion of the strings, the data are transferred bit-by-bit from client to server and vice versa.

Due to that fact you can use characters which are actually not supported by `US7ASCII`. Be aware, in case your client uses a different character set (e.g. when you use ODP.NET Managed Driver in an Windows application) the data will be rubbish! Also if you would consider a database character set migration you have the same issue.

Another note: I don't think you would get the same behavior with other character sets, e.g. if your database and your client both would use `WE8ISO8859P1` for example. Also be aware that you actually have wrong configuration. Your database uses character set `US7ASCII`, your `NLS_LANG` value is also `US7ASCII` (most likely it is not set at all and Oracle defaults it to `US7ASCII`) but the real character set of SQL*Plus, resp. your `cmd.exe` terminal is most likely [CP950](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_950) or [CP936](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_1386).

If you like to set everything properly you can either set your environment variable `NLS_LANG=.ZHT16MSWIN950` (CP936 seems to be not supported by Oracle) or change your codepage before running `sqlplus.exe` with command `chcp 437`. With this proper settings you will not see any Chinese characters as you probably would have expected.

Comment: thanks for the explanation =) . i think i got it hehe ;)