# How to store Chinese charachters in we8nswin1252 oracle database from .net application without changing database charachterset?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oracle, chinese-locale

I want my asp .net application to store Chinese charachters in WE8MSWIN1252 oracle 12c database, which oracle client should I use without changing db Charachterset.

I'm using windows server, I'v tried to set nls_lang in registry to Chinese charachterset but my app still store charachter like ??? in database.

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer:**

You cannot store Chinese characters if your database character set is `WE8MSWIN1252`. Setting `NLS_LANG` has nothing to do with the ability to store characters in a database.

**Long answer:**

Usually the National Character Set (check with `SELECT * FROM V$NLS_PARAMETERS WHERE PARAMETER = 'NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET';`) of a database support full Unicode, nowadays the default should be `AL16UTF16`. Use `NVARCHAR2`, `NCHAR`, `NCLOB` data type for columns where you like to store Chinese characters.

A workaround could be to convert your string to BASE64 and store these in your database, see [Base64 encoding and decoding in oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3804279/base64-encoding-and-decoding-in-oracle/3806265#40852152)

For another ugly and very dangerous workaround see this one: [difference between NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET abd NLS_CHARACTERSET for Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36710360/difference-between-nls-nchar-characterset-abd-nls-characterset-for-oracle/36712457#36712457)