# php - Convert € from ISO-8859-1 to ORACLE char set AL16UTF16

Tags: php, oracle, character-encoding, oracle10g

I'm trying to insert € character in oracle database.
my encoding is `ISO-8859-1` and the database is :

```
NLS_CHARACTERSET    WE8MSWIN1252
NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET  AL16UTF16
```

all character has been inserted correctly but when I try with € symbol I get an `?` mark.

Any one have any idea about this issu and how can I convert my character to insert the € symbol in my oracle database.

Comment: What front-end are you using to view the character stored in the database? SQL\*Plus? Toad? SQL Developer? And - are you on Windows or Unix? There is probably a mismatch between the character set used by your front-end and what Oracle thinks it is.

Comment: `ISO-8859-1` does not have the € currency symbol. Use another character set which supports it, e.g. [ISO-8859-15](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-15)

Comment: @mathguy I am using sql developer and my front-end on Unix env

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit How can I change my encoding? doing that with `mb_convert_encoding`  doesn't resolve the problem

Comment: Value of `mb_convert_encoding‌​` must match value of environment variable `NLS_LANG`, see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33783902/odbcconnection-returning-chinese-characters-as/33790600#33790600