# Oracle server encoding and file encoding

Tags: oracle, encoding

I have a **Oracle server** with a `DAD` defined with `PlsqlNLSLanguage DANISH_DENMARK.WE8ISO8859P1.`

I also have a `JavaScript` file that is loaded in the browser. The `JavaScript` file contains the danish letters **æøå**. When the **js file** is saved as `UTF8` the danish letters are misencoded. When I save **js file** as `UTF8-BOM` or `ANSI` then the letters are shown correctly.

I am not sure what is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set your DAD

```
PlsqlNLSLanguage DANISH_DENMARK.UTF8
```

or even better

```
PlsqlNLSLanguage DANISH_DENMARK.AL32UTF8
```

When you save your file as `ANSI` it typically means "Windows Codepage 1252" on Western Windows, see column "ANSI codepage" at [National Language Support (NLS) API Reference](https://www.microsoft.com/resources/msdn/goglobal/default.mspx). CP1252 is very similar to ISO-8859-1, see [ISO 8859-1 vs. Windows-1252](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8859-1#ISO_8859-1_vs._ISO_8859-15_vs._Windows-1252_vs._Unicode) (it is the German Wikipedia, however that table shows the differences much better than the English Wikipedia). Hence for a 100% correct setting you would have to set `PlsqlNLSLanguage DANISH_DENMARK.WE8MSWIN1252`.

Now, why do you get correct characters when you save your file as `UTF8-BOM`, although there is a mismatch with `.WE8ISO8859P1`?

When the browser opens the file it first reads the [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) `0xEF,0xBB,0xBF` and **assumes** the file encoded as UTF-8. However, this may fail in some circumstances, e.g. when you insert text from a `input` field to database.

With `PlsqlNLSLanguage DANISH_DENMARK.AL32UTF8` you tell the Oracle Database: "The web-server uses UTF-8." No more, no less (in terms of character set encoding). So, when your database uses character set `WE8ISO8859P1` then the Oracle driver knows he has to convert ISO-8859-1 characters coming from database to UTF-8 for the browser - and vice versa.

Comment: I did try to set the DAD and it worked. I just don't understand why. The Oracle docs states that `WE8ISO8859P1` supports Danish
https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/NLSPG/ch2charset.htm#NLSPG164

Comment: See my update where I try to explain. `PlsqlNLSLanguage .AL32UTF8` does **not** mean the **database** character set. It specifies the character set of the client, here the web-server. See also [NLS_LANG and others](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33783902/odbcconnection-returning-chinese-characters-as/33790600#33790600) which works in the same way.

Comment: If I change the DAD to `PlsqlNLSLanguage DANISH_DENMARK.AL32UTF8` and save the **js file** as `ANSI` then the danish letters are misencoded. Should it not be compatible?

Is it recommended to set the server as `PlsqlNLSLanguage DANISH_DENMARK.AL32UTF8` and save all files as UTF8?

Comment: UTF-8 (i.e. AL32UTF8) is compatible to ANSI (i.e. CP1252) only for first 127 characters (i.e. U+0000 to U+007F). Characters above do not match. Yes, nowadays you should work with UTF-8 wherever you can.

Comment: Im sorry, but I still dont understand why the letters 
**æ ø å** are misencoded. [this](http://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_html_ansi.asp) shows that the letters are supported.

In any case, it helped by changing everything to UTF-8

Comment: Yes, but for example **æ** is `xC6` at CP1252 and ISO-8859-1 but at UTF-8 it is `xC3 xA6`, i.e. they are represented by different byte values.