# Insert Special characters 'Mongolian tögrög' and symbol '₮' in Oracle Database

Tags: oracle, character-encoding

I need to insert currency `Mongolian tögrög` and symbol `₮` to Oracle Database.
The insert query as :

```
INSERT INTO CURRENCY (CUR_ISO_ID, CUR_ISO_CODE, CUR_DESC, CUR_DECIMAL_PLACE, CUR_SYMBOL) 
              VALUES (496,'MNT','Mongolian tögrög',2,'₮');
```

results as:

```
 CUR_ISO_ID | CUR | CUR_DESC         | CUR_DECIMAL_PLACE | CUR_SYMBOL |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
 496        | MNT | Mongolian t?gr?g | 2                 | .          |
```

Kindly advise on how to get the special characters inserted as is to the Database? i.e. the symbol not as `.` but `₮` and the description not as `Mongolian t?gr?g` but `Mongolian tögrög`. Please help.

Comment: Sorry about the pl/sql (edited my question now). I would only need an insert query which can allow insert of the special characters into Database.

Comment: You can use `dump()` to see what is actually stored. It might be that your session and/or OS character sets aren't displaying the stored characters properly, rather than them not being stored as you want. What is your database character set,  and client, and your NLS_LANG setting (if using SQL\*Plus; or equivalent otherwise), and your OS character set?

Comment: Which tool do you use to insert/select the data? What is your database `NLS_CHARACTERSET`

Comment: NLS_CHARACTERSET - AL32UTF8. I am using SQL*Plus to run the INSERT query.

Answer (score 1):

Before you launch your SQL*Plus enter these commands:

```
chcp 65001
set NLS_LANG=.AL32UTF8
```

- The first command sets codepage of `cmd.exe` to `UTF-8`.
- The second command tells your database: "I am using UTF-8"

Then you sql should work. I don't think there is any 8-bit Windows codepage `125x` which supports Mongolian tögrög.

See also this post to get some more information: [NLS_LANG and others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33783902/odbcconnection-returning-chinese-characters-as/33790600#33790600)

Check also this discussion [how to use sqlplus with utf8 on windows command line](https://community.oracle.com/thread/600575), there is an issue when you use UTF-8 at command line.

Comment: Question : I have the same problem and need to execute the same set NLS_LANG=.AL32UTF8, but after insert script execution. The database will remain with the new NLS_LANG value or remain with the old one ?

Comment: NLS_LANG affects only the client site but does not change anything on database.