# Oracle Spool unable to display special characters

Tags: sql, oracle

I am generateing a txt file using the below code. The code works fine, but there are issues with some characters. I am using Oracle.
Characters such as é, á etc. are unable to be displayed.

```
set echo off
set verify off
set termout on
set heading off
set pages 50000
set feedback off
set newpage none
set linesize 1000
set serveroutput off
set pagesize 0
set trimout on
set trimspool on


spool Weekly_Members_Vendors.txt

select   ''||Unique_ID||''||Name||''||Alt_Name||''|| Entity_Type||''||Party_Type||''||Reference_#||''||Addr1||''||Addr2||''||
     Addr3||''||Town||''||County||''||Postcode||''||Country||''||ALT_ADDRESS1||''||ALT_ADDRESS2||''||
     ALT_ADDRESS3||''||ALT_TOWN||''||ALT_COUNTY||''||ALT_POST_CODE||''||ALT_COUNTRY||''||NATIONALITY||''||
     DOB||''||INDIVIDUAL_ID||''||INDIVIDUAL_ID_TYPE||''||COUNTRY_OF_REGISTRATION||''||COMPANY_ID||''||COMPANY_ID_TYPE||''||
     SOURCE_COUNTRY||''||SOURCE_SYSTEM||''||TRANSACTION_TYPE
from     dbo.Temp_Weekly_Export_File;



spool off;

exit
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you run this in SQL*Plus on Windows.

In this case, check code page of command line windows by `chcp`

Usually it should be CP437 or CP850 (depending if you are in Europe or US).

Then before you start SQL*Plus set your `NLS_LANG` value accordingly, either as Environment Variable (e.g. `set NLS_LANG=WE8PC850`)

or

in Registry (`HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\ORACLE\KEY_%ORACLE_HOME_NAME%\NLS_LANG` for 32-bit, resp. `HKLM\SOFTWARE\ORACLE\KEY_%ORACLE_HOME_NAME%\NLS_LANG` for 64-bit)

You can also change the code page of command line window, e.g. `chcp 1252`

See also these answers:

[Unicode characters in Windows command line - how?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388490/unicode-characters-in-windows-command-line-how/33475373#33475373)

[OdbcConnection returning Chinese Characters as "?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33783902/odbcconnection-returning-chinese-characters-as/33790600#33790600)