# Character set issue while writing to oracle DB using python script

Tags: python, oracle, python-2.7, spotfire, codepages

i am writing to a oracle table using python script in spotfire. i am picking value from spotfire and inserting it to db using following part of script.

```
from Spotfire.Dxp.Data.Import import DatabaseDataSource, DatabaseDataSourceSettings, DataTableDataSource
objID = Document.Properties["OBJID"]
objectname = Document.Properties["ObjName"]
sqlIns = sqlIns + "insert into mytablename (OBJ_ID,OBJ_NAME) VALUES ('" + objID + "','" + objectname + "')" 
print sqlIns
dbsettings = DatabaseDataSourceSettings( "System.Data.OracleClient","Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=xxxx.com)(PORT=1530))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=xxx)));User Id=xxxx;Password=xxx",sqlIns)
ds = DatabaseDataSource(dbsettings)
newDataTable = Document.Data.Tables.Add("temp",ds)
Document.Data.Tables.Remove(newDataTable)
```

This is working fine when values in OBJ_NAME is in English,when i am inserting  OBJ_NAME in other languages such as korean data base is showing values like "¿¿¿¿¿¿ ¿¿¿ ¿ MD -¿¿¿". 
But when i printed above python code i can see that it displayed correct korean character. please see the image below.

[image]

But In oracle its not showing correctly. See screenshot of oracle table below
[image]

As data type of OBJ_NAME in oracle is Nvarchar ,if i insert this Korean value from oracle itself ,it will insert correct Korean character.

Comment: What is your `NLS_LANG` value on the client?

Comment: On Oracle ,NLS_LANGUAGE is AMERICAN and NLS_CHARACTERSET is AL32UTF8

Comment: That was not my question, I asked for `NLS_LANG` on your client, not the  character set of your database. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33783902/odbcconnection-returning-chinese-characters-as/33790600#33790600 for more details.

Comment: AMERICAN_AMERICA.WE8MSWIN1252  
 .

Comment: `WE8MSWIN1252` does not support Korean characters. Try `AMERICAN_AMERICA.AL32UTF8`. Also check settings of your editor, IDE.

Comment: i tried by chnaging WE8MSWIN1252 to AL32UTF8  but it didnt work.could you tell me how andwhat to check IDE editor?

Comment: Which editor do you use?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try encoding to utf-8 in python script.

Comment: Hi Leo
thanks for replying. Appreciate your help.
Even though its not a direct method, i tried writing to db by encoding to utf-8 ( .encode('utf-8') ) in python script and then reading it back in spotfire by decoding back . But that work around also didn't work as expected. I am getting unsupported characters.