# Oracle sqlplus execute files of different encoding

Tags: oracle, encoding, sqlplus

I have a batch file that execute SQL scripts through sqlplus:

```
(
   echo @"./myUTF8.sql"
   echo @"./myAnsi.sql"
) | sqlplus uset/pwd@mybd
```

Unfortunately these SQL scripts are generated in different encoding, Ansi, UTF8, ...

How can I tell sqlplus that a script is of a specified encoding?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to change encoding with command `chcp`, e.g. `chcp 65001` for UTF-8 or `chcp 1252` for Windows 1252. Term "ANSI" is just a general name for many different encodings. See column "ANSI codepage" at this [National Language Support (NLS) API Reference](https://web.archive.org/web/20171015144140/https://www.microsoft.com/resources/msdn/goglobal/default.mspx) to get codepage for you locale.

If you have to change the encoding inside a SQL script use `host chcp ...`

However, you also have to set `NLS_LANG` environment variable accordingly. So after you have changed codepage you must also run for example `SET NLS_LANG=.AL32UTF8` or `SET NLS_LANG=.WE8MSWIN1252`.

See [OdbcConnection returning Chinese Characters as "?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33783902/odbcconnection-returning-chinese-characters-as/33790600#33790600) for more details.

Answer (score 7):

I have a SQL script created in UTF8, to run it with sqlplus in Linux, before open sqlplus do

```
export NLS_LANG=.AL32UTF8
```

then use sqlplus to load the script.

Answer (score 0):

sqlplus 19.x / windows 10 / command prompt

Setting "host chcp 65001" in the sql script itself does not help, nor in a "set_sqlplus_params.sql" called before the sql script to execute.

The only help was to set it as environment variable in the shell itself:

```
set SET NLS_LANG=.AL32UTF8
```

and then call sqlplus for executing the script in UTF-8.