# Issue in storing value in Nvarchar column in Oracle

Tags: oracle, character-encoding

I have a table with NVarchar column in oracle.When I inserted below value it converted into some other characters.

```
Insert INTO tbltest (CONTENT) Values(N'✓ à la mode δ')
Select * From tbltest

CONTENT
--------------------
¿ à la mode d
```

So what datatype should i take to save this type of data.Please suggest.

Comment: Which tool do you use to invoke this command?

Comment: Oracle SQL Developer. Same thing happened in C# code when geting data from table.

Comment: Which provider/driver to you use in C#? ODBC? OleDB? ODP.NET?, ...?

Comment: System.Data.OracleClient

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For SQL Developer I don't know exact solution but check settings in Tools -> Preferences -> Environment -> Encoding.

Select an encoding which supports your characters, e.g. UTF-8

Regarding your C# Code:

**Microsoft .NET Framework Data Provider for Oracle** is [deprecated](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/77d8yct7%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for many years, you should not use it in new projects. I think development stopped 20 years ago, thus it does not support Unicode characters - you cannot use it.

Use a modern provider, e.g. "Oracle Data Provider for .NET (ODP.NET)", you can download it from here: [Oracle Data Access Components (ODAC) for Windows Downloads](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/downloads/net-downloads-160392.html)

In case of "Oracle Data Provider for .NET" you have to set `NLS_LANG` to an encoding which support these characters, e.g. `.AL32UTF8`. You can set `NLS_LANG` either as Environment variable or in Registry at `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\ORACLE\KEY_%ORACLE_HOME_NAME%\NLS_LANG` (for 32 bit), resp. `HKLM\SOFTWARE\ORACLE\KEY_%ORACLE_HOME_NAME%\NLS_LANG` (for 64 bit).

Other providers (e.g. `ODP.NET Managed Driver` or Oracle `OraOLEDB`) are not NLS_LANG sensitive.

See more information here: [OdbcConnection returning Chinese Characters as "?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33783902/odbcconnection-returning-chinese-characters-as/33790600#33790600)

Comment: Thanks Wernfried Domscheit, after character set  change it's working fine.

Comment: After changing charset from WE8MSWIN1252 to AL32UTF8 the existing clob column data are converted into other language. Looks like 瑯捫數灥捴敤晦睤慴攧㸼⅛䍄䅔䅛嵝㸼⽄ and in code it is not get back as previously it is stored.

Comment: How to you select? With the same tools?

Answer (score -1):

This is due to your NLS_CHARACTERSET, NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET database settings and NLS_LANG settings ar your client end where you are seeing. 
As your value has special character specific to your language, you need to set  with that. Like below

Comment: You cannot set `NLS_LANG` with `ALTER SESSION`. It must be set in Environment variable or in Registry.