# PLSQL Special Character in input parameter is not being passed

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, sqlplus

Please find below my function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION TESTER_TESTING (    P_STRING         IN VARCHAR2) 
RETURN NUMBER IS
BEGIN
Dbms_Output.Put_Line('P_STRING:'||P_STRING);
return 1;
END TESTER_TESTING;
/
```

When i execute from sqlplus using:

```
DECLARE 
  RetVal NUMBER;
  P_STRING VARCHAR2(32767);

BEGIN 
  P_STRING := '006µ-540';
  RetVal := VISION.TESTER_TESTING ( P_STRING );
  DBMS_OUTPUT.Put_Line('RetVal = ' || TO_CHAR(RetVal));
  DBMS_OUTPUT.Put_Line('');
COMMIT; 
END; 
/
```

Output is:
P_STRING:006??-540
RetVal = 1

[image: Output]

Please advise on why the special character is not being passed & how to fix it.

```
-Oracle Version: 11g
-Linux: RHEL 7.2
-Script executed using sqlplus.
```

Comment: When executed using Toad. It is passing the value properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL*Plus inherits character encoding from command-line. You can interrogate by `chcp`.

Before you start sqlplus you must set `NLS_LANG` parameter accordingly, e.g.

```
C:\>chcp
Active code page: 850

C:\>SET NLS_LANG=.WE8PC850    
C:\>sqlplus ...
```

Of course it also works the other way around, e.g.

```
C:\>echo %NLS_LANG%
NLS_LANG=AMERICAN_AMERICA.WE8MSWIN1252

C:\>chcp 1252
Active code page: 1252

C:\>sqlplus ...
```

`NLS_LANG` can be also set in Registry, see `HKLM\SOFTWARE\ORACLE\KEY_%ORACLE_HOME_NAME%\NLS_LANG` (for 64 bit), resp. `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\ORACLE\KEY_%ORACLE_HOME_NAME%\NLS_LANG` (for 32 bit Oracle at 64 bit Windows).

Have a look at this post for further details: [OdbcConnection returning Chinese Characters as "?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33783902/odbcconnection-returning-chinese-characters-as/33790600#33790600)

I just see, you use Linux, not Windows. Use `locale charmap` or `echo $LANG` instead of `chcp` to get character set of your terminal.

Comment: Hi, what you have explained works well with windows however I am still facing the same issue in Linux. $LANG = en_US.UTF-8 and our Oracle DB has AMERICAN_AMERICA.AL32UTF8. Please advise. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Maybe your terminal program does not support it. Check settings there.

Comment: For terminal program we are using PuTTY in which we have mentioned UTF-8 as Remote character set.

Comment: Also when using sqlldr we are using the following syntax : "load data
CHARACTERSET UTF8 infile..... " which correctly identifies and loads data properly from the same terminal program & linux server.

Comment: Did you try `export NLS_LANG=AMERICAN_AMERICA.AL32UTF8` ?

Comment: For reference: [link](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12102_01/books/AnyInstAdm784/AnyInstAdmPreInstall18.html)

Answer (score 0):

Oracle is returning ASCII CODE of µ as 49845 (In my case) . However ASCII code of µ is 230 as per mentioned in ASCII chart available on internet. So definately 49845 ascii code coming from database to client machine when gets converted to some "I dont know " figure.

Comment: `ASCII` is a 7-bit code and does not contain `µ` at all.

Comment: I referred http://www.asciitable.com/. It mentions under extended ascii codes. But 49845 (returned from oracle) is definately something else which i dont understand

Comment: 49845 is `µ` encoded in UTF-8, see [Micro Sign U+00B5](https://unicode-table.com/en/00B5/)

Comment: Thanks @WernfriedDomscheit . So should i think that this encoding will not be  recognised at client machine ?

Comment: Same issue, you have to tell the client by `NLS_LANG` which character set shall be used.