# strange character in migration from postgres to oracle (Ansi)

Tags: oracle, postgresql, csv, encoding, character-encoding

I'm migrating a db from postgres to oracle.I create csv files with this command:

\copy ttt to 'C:\test\ttt.csv'  CSV DELIMITER ',' HEADER  encoding 'UTF8' quote as '"'; then with oracle sql loader I put data in oracle tables.
It's all ok but I have in some description this character Â that wasnt in the original DB.
The encoding of db postgres is UTF8 and I'm on a window machine.
Thanks to all.
Gian Piero

Comment: Before you start sqlloader run `set NLS_LANG=.AL32UTF8` and `chcp 65001`

Comment: Ok.It works.Thanks you.Two questions: 1)do you understand why there is this problem?          2) My sql loader is triggered by a java program Do you think it is enough to run this command from the command line from which you will launch java or should i run it from the program itself? Anyway I'm doing tests now

Comment: Provided more information as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you start sqlloader run

```
chcp 65001    
set NLS_LANG=.AL32UTF8
```

- `chcp 65001` sets codepage of your `cmd.exe` to `UTF-8` (which is inherited by sqlloader and sqlplus)
- With `set NLS_LANG=.AL32UTF8` you tell the Oracle database "The client uses UTF-8"

Without these commands you would have this situation (due to defaults)

```
chcp 850
set NLS_LANG=AMERICAN_AMERICA.US7ASCII
```

Maybe on your PC you have codepage 437 instead of 850, it depends whether your PC is U.S. or Europe, see [National Language Support (NLS) API Reference](https://www.microsoft.com/resources/msdn/goglobal/default.mspx), column `OEM codepage`

You can set `NLS_LANG` also as Environment Variable in PC settings or you can define it in Registry at `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\ORACLE\KEY_%ORACLE_HOME_NAME%\NLS_LANG` (for 32 bit), resp. `HKLM\SOFTWARE\ORACLE\KEY_%ORACLE_HOME_NAME%\NLS_LANG`

You can also change codepage of your `cmd.ext` persistent, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/33475373/3027266

For details about NLS_LANG see https://stackoverflow.com/a/33790600/3027266