# Accents Oracle - special characters

Tags: oracle

I'm changing a php server application from windows to Linux, when I query special characters from the Oracle database I always get `?`. on the windows server I make this query

```
SQL> select length ('ñ') from dual;

LENGTH ('Ñ')
-----------
           1
```

and in linux it generates this

```
SQL> select length ('ñ') from dual;

LENGTH ('??')
------------
            2
```

Comment: SQL> select value from   nls_database_parameters where  parameter = 'NLS_CHARACTERSET';

VALUE
----------------------------------------
WE8ISO8859P1

SQL> select value from   v$nls_parameters  where  parameter = 'NLS_CHARACTERSET';

VALUE
----------------------------------------------------------------
WE8ISO8859P1

Comment: Please edit you question for additional information instead of putting them as comment.

Answer (score 0):

You must set your `NLS_LANG` variable according to character set of your Linux.

Check character set with `locale charmap` or echo `$LANG`
Then set `NLS_LANG` accordingly, e.g. `export NLS_LANG=AMERICAN_AMERICA.AL32UTF8`

See 
[OdbcConnection returning Chinese Characters as "?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33783902/odbcconnection-returning-chinese-characters-as/33790600#33790600) for more details.