# Oracle database encoding and decoding

Tags: database, oracle, utf-8

I'm running an SQL file with Shell script (.sh) contains an update statement but one of the columns is not inserted as needed, I tried to convert the file encoding to UTF-8 with notepad++ but the issue still in place.

**bellow you will find the current value of the column and the correct version of it**

```
current (issue):
R��servation

required:
Réservation
```

Comment: Make sure that the NLS_LANG setting of the client is set to retrieve french characters

Comment: NLS_LANG setting of the client is already set

Answer (score 1):

You must set the encoding of your shell according to `NLS_LANG` value.

On Windows it would be for example:

```
C:\>chcp 65001
Active code page: 65001

C:\>set NLS_LANG=.AL32UTF8

C:\>sqlplus ...
```

See also [OdbcConnection returning Chinese Characters as "?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33783902/odbcconnection-returning-chinese-characters-as/33790600#33790600)

Comment: how to do it the .sh file ?

Comment: @AbdeAMNR, with `NLS_LANG` you tell the Oracle DB which encoding is used in your file. If you converted the file to UTF-8 then you must set `NLS_LANG=.AL32UTF8` (language and territory are optional). If you work just with your terminal and sqlplus run `locale charmap` or `echo $LANG` to interrogate the encoding of your terminal. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33783902/odbcconnection-returning-chinese-characters-as/33790600#33790600