# Non-english letters in sql script problem - Oracle Sql Developer

Tags: sql, oracle, unicode, import, non-english

I'm executing some random script to my local database and I have problem with non-english letters. When I'm executing the same insert statement directly from sql develeoper everything is ok. Could somebody explain my how can I avoid this problem using sql script?
Example. Everything works okay.
Statement: `insert into my_table values ('aaaaała');`
Result: 'aaaaała';

[image]

Now I'm pasting the same insert statement into my sql file(script.sql) and I'm wirting:

```
@'D:\script.sql';
```

'D:\' - it is location of that file
Statement: `insert into my_table values ('aaaaała');`
Result: 'aaaaała';

The result is wrong:

[image]

My settings:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You must set your `NLS_LANG` value according to the character set of the `script.sql` file. Typically you set this in the options in at the "Save" dialog.

For example if the .sql file was saved as UTF-8 then you must run:

```
set NLS_LANG=.AL32UTF8
sqlplus .... @'D:\script.sql';
```

See also [OdbcConnection returning Chinese Characters as "?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33783902/odbcconnection-returning-chinese-characters-as/33790600#33790600) for more details.

Comment: It doesn't work, when my .sql file is coding in UTF-8. When I change the sql file character set settings from UTF-8 to ANSI it works okay..

Comment: @drk, did a typo, must be `AL32UTF8` instead of `AL432UTF8`