# Set the NLS_LANG

Tags: oracle, utf-8, nls-lang

We have a database with `AL32UTF8` as character set. Our application supports EN, FR, DE and JP languages. In Each release we insert new labels into the table managing the translations. what the `NLS_LANG` of the client should be, to ensure that french special characters and Japanese are inserted correctly into the database ?

Please note that each client has his own database.
Is there any automatic way to ensure that the used `NLS_LANG` is the good one ?
I have already read [this article](https://gerardnico.com/db/oracle/nls_lang#how_to_determine_the_nls_lang) but I do not know how can I achieve this.
Thanks,
Bilel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have to deal with Japanese and European languages then `AL32UTF8` (i.e. UTF-8) is actually the only useful option.

The linked article is has some flaws, for example "*...on a Windows operating system, then you should not set AL32UTF8 as the client character set in the NLS_LANG parameter because there are no UTF-8 WIN32 clients.*" That's wrong, nowadays almost every windows client is UTF-8 capable. Every text editor you use to write `*sql` files supports UTF-8, when you use plain sql*Plus then a simple `chcp 65001` command makes it UTF-8. Only the ancient and deprecated drivers from Microsoft do not support Unicode.

Please recognize, when you set for example `NLS_LANG=.AL32UTF8` value then you tell the Oracle database: "My client application uses characters set AL32UTF8 (a.k.a. UTF-8)" - no more, no less.

It does not automatically mean that your client application is really using UTF-8, many times you have to specify it explicitly in some settings (however there are applications and drivers which automatically follow the `NLS_LANG` value).

See [OdbcConnection returning Chinese Characters as "?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33783902/odbcconnection-returning-chinese-characters-as/33790600#33790600) for more information.