# Linux server application consulting Oracle with NLS_CHARACTERSET WE8ISO8859P1 (problems with accentuation)

Tags: oracle, utf-8, centos

I have a web application developed by third parties running on CentOS consulting an Oracle database. The database is configured as follows:

```
NLS_LANGUAGE = BRAZILIAN PORTUGUESE 
NLS_TERRITORY = BRAZIL 
NLS_CHARACTERSET = WE8ISO8859P1 
NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET = AL16UTF16
```

Syntax of the CONVERT command:

```
CONVERT (string_expression, to_data_set [, from_data_set]);
```

example:

```
SELECT
   CONVERT ('Ä Ê Í', 'US7ASCII', 'WE8ISO8859P1')
FROM
   DUAL;
```

In my case, I'm trying to do as follows:

```
SELECT
CONVERT (expression, 'UTF8', 'WE8ISO8859P1')
FROM ...
```

But I can't find the correct combination of to_data_set and from_data_set to display the accented characters correctly with my query.

Any suggestion (including a different approach than using CONVERT command)?

Comment: Oracle [discourages the use of the convert function](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/CONVERT.html), and has for a long time. Have you looked at the alternatives mentioned in that note? And are you sure the display issue is because of the DB character set(s), rather than the client/web application/browser settings?

Comment: Yes, I checked the suggestions given when creating this post and none of them apply to my problem. As for modifying the application environment, I thought about it too and made several changes without success (this is a third-party application, without developer support). I know the status given by Oracle to CONVERT, so I also ask for an alternative solution.

Comment: What data type is `string_expression` - varchar2 or nvarchar2?

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33783902/odbcconnection-returning-chinese-characters-as/33790600#33790600 set your local NLS_LANG properly.

Comment: string_expression is VARCHAR2 (2160 BYTE).

Comment: Just a guess, but have you tried defining `string_expression varchar2(2160 CHAR)` yet?

Comment: Well, probably `string_expression varchar2(2000 CHAR)` (or less!) to stay under 4000 bytes for legacy `VARCHAR2` size constraint.