# how to upload special characters with sql loader

Tags: oracle, character-encoding, special-characters, sql-loader

I have a file with special characters. How do I have to activate the encoding to allow uploading this information.

file.txt

```
11|campo2|09/13/2017 11:36:11 PM
12|cáéíóúñ12345aeiou|09/22/2017 02:41:38 PM
```

select * from nls_session_parameters;

[image]

[image]

ControlFile.ctl

```
OPTIONS (SILENT=(ALL, HEADER))
load data
infile file.txt
badfile file.bad
discardfile file.dis
append
into table TABLE_INFO
fields terminated by '|'
TRAILING NULLCOLS (
  SUB_ID INTEGER EXTERNAL,
  SUB_PROPERTY CHAR(4000),
  MODIFY_TIME DATE TERMINATED BY "|" "to_date(:MODIFY_TIME, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS PM')",
  UPLOAD_DATE DATE TERMINATED BY "|" "to_date('20201215153045', 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS')",
  FILE_NAME constant "nombre_archivo.txt"
)
```

Table

```
create table TABLE_INFO
(
  sub_id       NUMBER(20) not null,
  sub_property VARCHAR2(4000),
  modify_time  DATE,
  upload_date  DATE,
  file_name    VARCHAR2(200)
)
```

```
sqlldr userbd/passbd control=ControlFile.ctl log=log_file.log rows=10000 direct=true
```

Comment: Please don't paste images, provide result as formatted text (https://www.convertcsv.com/csv-to-flat-file.htm or https://senseful.github.io/text-table/ may help)

Comment: `NLS_SESSION_PARAMETERS` is useless - your `sqlldr` will run in a different session, it does not show the **database** character set and no view shows your `NLS_LANG` parameter

Answer (score 0):

There are three points you have to consider:

1. Ensure that your database is able to store such characters. This can be interrogated by

   ```
   SELECT * 
   FROM V$NLS_PARAMETERS 
   WHERE PARAMETER IN ('NLS_CHARACTERSET', 'NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET')
   ```

   View `NLS_DATABASE_PARAMETERS` will also work
2. On your client use a character set which supports such characters. On Windows you could do for example `chcp 65001` in order to set UTF-8
3. Tell the Oracle database which character set is used by your client. This is typically done by the `NLS_LANG` parameter, e.g. `SET NLS_LANG=SPANISH_SPAIN.AL32UTF8`

In your sqlldr control file you can set also

```
CHARACTERSET character_set_name
```

which takes precedence over `NLS_LANG` character set value (see [Data File Character Sets](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SUTIL/GUID-B0CCE864-0CB2-4D6A-BAC6-F9C06C38844B.htm#SUTIL1083)).

See also [OdbcConnection returning Chinese Characters as "?"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33783902/odbcconnection-returning-chinese-characters-as/33790600#33790600)

NB, for proper import of `DATE` values the field should be specified like

```
MODIFY_TIME DATE 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS PM'
```