# Can I use multiple NLS_LANG in same sql loader?

Tags: special-characters, loader, sql-loader, nls-lang

I have a situation where my Oracle sql loader has to support 4 character sets. The loader script is common and loads files from multiple country sources, hence the requirement.

At the moment, the value of a field coming from file is 1àáâäåèéêëîïñóòôöùûüÿßçtecseven, and after the loader loads this file in the table, the value is seen  �������������tecseven

Now, I checked my env file and currently it has the following value set for parameter:

```
export NLS_LANG=AMERICAN_AMERICA.AL32UTF8
```

My question, how can I further add other NLS_LANG parameter values like
NLS_LANG=FRENCH_FRANCE.AL32UTF8, NLS_LANG=GERMAN_GERMANY.AL32UTF8 etc?

TIA.

[how to upload special characters with sql loader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65135852/how-to-upload-special-characters-with-sql-loader)