# Sqlplus cannot get special characters like Japanese from the query result

Tags: oracle, sqlplus, globalization

I use sqlplus 12 connecting to Oracle 12c.
I have set the environment variable NLS_LANG = AMERICAN_AMERICA.JA16SJISTILDE.
I changed region and Langue for non-Unicode program to japanese.
But still can't display Japanese correctly. Can someone help me find the problem? Thank alot

[NLS_LANG image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p8XOJ.png)

[Problem image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IIVfI.png)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33783902/odbcconnection-returning-chinese-characters-as/33790600#33790600

Comment: Thank you again, it really helped me.