# oracle saving non english characters not working via script

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, sql-insert, non-english

I have c# program that fills me database with values, but when I try to export them to import.sql and then run import.sql script it always fill database with special characters and not czech letters.

Via example

I have this table

```
CREATE TABLE Document
(
    "Id" NUMBER(19,0) GENERATED BY DEFAULT ON NULL AS IDENTITY MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 9999999999999999999999999999 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 1 CACHE 20 NOORDER  NOCYCLE  NOKEEP  NOSCALE , 
    "name" NVARCHAR2(200), 
    "fullname" NVARCHAR2(300)
) SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE 
  PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 
 NOCOMPRESS LOGGING
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "USERS" ;
```

and when I export data for example `1, "Velmi přívětivý dokument", "Dokument který byl velmi přívětivý do doby než SQL přeházelo písmenka"`

and insert inside import.sql looks like this

```
CREATE TABLE Document
(
    "Id" NUMBER(19,0) GENERATED BY DEFAULT ON NULL AS IDENTITY MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 9999999999999999999999999999 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 1 CACHE 20 NOORDER  NOCYCLE  NOKEEP  NOSCALE , 
    "name" NVARCHAR2(200), 
    "fullname" NVARCHAR2(300)
) SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE 
  PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 
 NOCOMPRESS LOGGING
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "USERS" ;

INSERT INTO Document ("Id","name","fullname") values (1, "Velmi přívětivý dokument", "Dokument který byl velmi přívětivý do doby než SQL přeházelo písmenka")
```

and run script (Using dockerd to host local db) I get special characters like this 'p��v�iv�' instead 'Přívětivý'

but when I run that INSERT inside SQL Developer it insert all czech characters inside db without any problem.
I am not really sure where the problem is.

Comment: How do you run the sqlfile? How do you export it? What is the character set of your database?

Comment: I tried to export it as UTF - 8, CP 1250, CP 1252 but it aint doing anything. Database is AL32UTF8 and I am running sqlfile by this command "docker run -p port:port -e ORACLE_PASSWORD=password-v /home/pc/init_scripts:/container-entrypoint-initdb.d gvenzl/oracle-xe"

Comment: Did you set `NLS_LANG` environment variable in your docker? If not set the Oracle defaults it to `NLS_LANG=AMERICAN_AMERICA.US7ASCII`, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33783902/odbcconnection-returning-chinese-characters-as/33790600#33790600

Comment: before I run that command in my previous comment I set NLS_LANG=EE8PC852 (Czech Lang) and still same issue .

Comment: You must set it to the format of your export, i.e. `NLS_LANG=.AL32UTF8` (don't miss the leading dot), respective `NLS_LANG=.EE8MSWIN1250` or `NLS_LANG=.WE8MSWIN1252`, depending on your export.

Answer (score 0):

You must set encoding, a.k.a. "code page" of your terminal (I assume `cmd.exe`, but I don't know docker) to the encoding of your export file. The default is neither UTF-8, nor CP1250, nor CP1252.

Most like it is CP437, CP850 or CP852 depending on your Windows language, see https://web.archive.org/web/20170916200715/http://www.microsoft.com/resources/msdn/goglobal/default.mspx

You can interrogate and change it with command `chcp`

Code Page Identifiers you can find [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/intl/code-page-identifiers?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

Comment: I use docker with bullseye (linux)

Comment: Then interrogate with `locale charmap` or echo `$LANG`. But I don't know how to set it. Otherwise do it the other way around and export the table in the character set of the terminal (provided it actually supports Czech characters)

Comment: `echo $LANG` -> en_US.UTF-8
`locale charmap` ->UTF-8
I exported table in UTF-8 and then run the script and I get again [] instead Czech characters. 
It's weird since exported utf-8 is saved with Czech letters but when I use script it mess up.

Comment: Yes, strange. Sorry, I don't know docker at all, so I cannot help you. However, the principle of my answer applies for any platform.