# Special characters (german umlauts) are displayed as ASCII

Tags: oracle, character-encoding, environment-variables, special-characters

In our database german umlauts are displayed as ASCII.
Here some examples

```
Ü is displayed as "š"
ä is displayed as "„" 
Ä is displayed as "Ž" 
ö is displayed as "”"
Ö is displayed as "™"
```

Here some Oracle enviroment variables:

```
SELECT distinct client_charset FROM v$session_connect_info
WHERE sid = sys_context('USERENV','SID');
retuns Unknown

select * from v$NLS_PARAMETERS;
NLS_LANGUAGE    GERMAN  
NLS_CHARACTERSET    WE8MSWIN1252
```

I have also noticed, that there is no `NLS_LANG` setted up.
Can someone give me any clue how to check if this is a problem of env variable or character-encoding itself? Or how to fix it so that the umlauts would be displayed correctly?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't think ASCII has characters like `ä`. You've also shared some characters that look like Czech. Do you mean that e.g. `Ü` displays as `š`? What client program are you using?

Comment: I mean I wish to see ä and I see „. I see this output in sqldeveloper and in toad.

Comment: What character set are your operating system and clients using - e.g. in SQL Developer, what do you have set under Tool->Preferences->Environment->Encoding?

Comment: I have encoding cp1252 .

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33783902/odbcconnection-returning-chinese-characters-as/33790600#33790600

Comment: A flagrant [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) case (example in Python): `'ÜäÄöÖ'.encode('cp437').decode('cp1250')` returns `'š„Ž”™'`.

Comment: @JosefZ thanks, that gives me the hint for correct answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first sentence is already wrong, it must be "my client application displays german umlauts as ..." Characters like `Ž` are not ASCII either. The Oracle environment variables have nothing to do how your client displays any characters.

There could be two reasons:

- Characters like `š „ Ž ” ™` are **really** stored in your database because they are inserted wrong, and you just think it should be `Ü ä Ä ö Ö`
- Your client uses the wrong character set.

`NLS_LANG` is used to tell the database "my client uses character set XYZ" - no more, no less! Well, some clients inherit the `NLS_LANG` value for own character set setting but that is not always the case.

**Actual answer:**

You have wrong data in your database! When you inserted the data then your client was using [CP437](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437) (Oracle Character Set `US8PC437`) but you did not tell this the database.

Most likely data was inserted by `sqlplus` which inherits the codepage from `cmd.exe` which is by default 437 on English Windows machines. `NLS_LANG` character set was set to `WE8MSWIN1252`. When character set of client and database is the same then data is transferred byte-by-byte without any conversion - there is the mismatch!

**Solutions:**

- Before you run your `sqlplus` script Set NLS_LANG accordingly, e.g.

  ```
  SET NLS_LANG=.US8PC437
  sqlplus ...
  ```

  Language and Territory are optional and thus can be skipped.
- Your database uses character set `WE8MSWIN1252`, then it would be beneficial to use it also by your client. By this you can insert and display any character which is supported by the database (no less but also no more)

  ```
  chcp 1252
  SET NLS_LANG=.WE8MSWIN1252
  sqlplus ...
  ```

**Correction of wrong data:**

In order to correct the wrong data try this:

```
UPDATE table_name SET column_name = CONVERT(column_name, 'WE8MSWIN1252', 'US8PC437');
```

Note, this should be a one-time correction only. Do not put such update as part of your application code!

**Update**

For correction of PL/SQL code, try this one (not tested):

Create a SQL script like this:

```
SET HEADING OFF 
SET FEEDBACK OFF 
SET NEWPAGE NONE 
SET VERIFY OFF 
SET TRIMSPOOL ON 
SET DEFINE OFF 
SET ECHO OFF 
SET TERMOUT OFF
SET PAGESIZE 0
SET LINESIZE 32767
SET LONG 2000000000
SET LONGCHUNKSIZE 32767 

spool PACKAGE_NAME.sql;
SELECT DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL('PACKAGE', 'PACKAGE_NAME', USER) FROM DUAL t;

spool OFF;
EXIT
```

And the run it like this

```
c:\> chcp 437
c:\> SET NLS_LANG=.WE8MSWIN1252
c:\> sqlplus -s ... @<above script>

c:\> SET NLS_LANG=.US8PC437
c:\> sqlplus ... @PACKAGE_NAME.sql
```

Comment: I see. For ü I get 81. Typ=1 CharacterSet=WE8MSWIN1252: 81,a

Comment: square is displayed as ü. And I get Typ=1 Len=1 CharacterSet=WE8MSWIN1252: 81 for square.

Comment: Thank you. Any chance to change dictionary tables? As it happens in comments of procedures/functions and packages...

Comment: What do you mean by "change dictionary tables"?

Comment: The problem occurs in source code of functions procedures and  packages which  I can see in sys.all_source view. And AFAIK they are stored in some dictionary tables which are read only. So I cant update them just so... And the amount is quite large as there are around 300 such source codes.

Comment: So this is not "normal" data but PL/SQL code? Simply re-deploy the code with proper client settings.

Comment: Ok, thanks! Is there any chance to do it automatically? As There are 300 of them and at least 1600 errors.

Comment: Please see my update

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241811/discussion-between-hajduk-and-wernfried-domscheit).