# Redeploying packages with EXECUTE IMMEDIATE

Tags: oracle, plsql, redeploy

I wish to redeploy some packages.
Here the simplified code:

```
vCode CLOB;
SELECT DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL('PACKAGE_BODY', 'MY_PACKAGE', USER) INTO vCode FROM DUAL t;
  
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE CONVERT(vCode, 'WE8MSWIN1252', 'US8PC437');
```

Would it be possible to check if the code would be compiled without errors?
And if so, run the `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` command?
Many thanks!

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish here (i.e. why would you want to redeploy code from the same database)?  Perhaps you just want to `alter package my_package compile body` to recompile the package body?

Comment: I wish to redeploy with converted encoding.  Here the line convert CONVERT(vCode, 'WE8MSWIN1252', 'US8PC437');

Comment: Related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71016315/special-characters-german-umlauts-are-displayed-as-ascii

Comment: Try it out. In case of an error it will raise exception `ORA-24344: success with compilation error`. Bear in mind, using this is a high risk. You should really use spooled SQL files, because the PL/SQL package will be overwritten even with errors, i.e. your original source code will be lost! Obviously you don't saved the source code somewhere else.

Comment: If this is a production system, shouldn't you be doing this conversion on the source code stored in Git or whatever source control system you use?

Comment: There is nothing like control system now. We are on the way to get it.

Comment: If you don't have the source code saved off in a version control system already, I would be **extremely** hesitant to try to do this sort of in-place conversion.  I would strongly suggest that you extract whatever code you have to the file system first and then re-run the SQL with the proper `SQL*Plus` settings.  That way if something doesn't go as expected, you at least have the source sitting on the file system to try again.

Comment: *"There is nothing like control system now. We are on the way to get it."* Putting your code under source control ought to be your **number one** priority.

Comment: Ok. Thanks all. Will put the code under version control.