# How to convert UTF8 data from PostgreSQL to AL32UTF8 Oracle DB?

Tags: postgresql, oracle, dblink

I have a task to import some data from Postgres database to Oracle via dblink

The connection between Postgres and Oracle works good, but unfortunately, when I try read data from created view (in Oracle database), I spotted a problem with data encoding - special national characters (Polish).

Source Postgres database have a UTF8 encoding, but Oracle have a AL32UTF8

Postgres:

```
select server_encoding
-

UTF8
```

Oracle:

```
select * from v$nls_parameters where parameter like '%CHARACTERSET';
-

PARAMETER VALUE

NLS_CHARACTERSET AL32UTF8
NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET AL16UTF16
```

When I use command "isql -v" (on destination machine with Oracle database) and later "select * from table;", everything works good, but when I use this same select from Oracle database using dblink my data encoding is broken

For example:
from odbc:
isql -v

```
select * from table;

[ID][Name]
0,Warszawa
1,Kraków
2,Gdańsk
```

from oracle using dblink:

```
select * from table@dblink;

[ID][Name]
0,Warszawa
1,KrakĂłw
2,GdaĹ„sk
```

/etd/odbc.ini:

```
[ODBC Data Sources]

[Postgres_DB]
Description         = Postgres_DB
Driver              = /usr/lib64/psqlodbcw.so
DSN                 = Postgres_DB
Trace               = Yes
TraceFile           = /tmp/odbc_sql_postgresdb.log
Database            = database
Servername          = server
UserName            = user
Password            = secret
Port                = 5432
Protocol            = 8.4
ReadOnly            = Yes
RowVersioning       = No
ShowSystemTables    = No
ShowOidColumn       = No
FakeOidIndex        = No
SSLmode             = require
Charset             = UTF8
```

$ORACLE_HOME/hs/admin/initPostgres_DB.ora:

```
HS_FDS_CONNECT_INFO = Postgres_DB
HS_FDS_TRACE_LEVEL=DEBUG
HS_FDS_SHAREABLE_NAME = /usr/lib64/libodbc.so
HS_FDS_SUPPORT_STATISTICS = FALSE
HS_LANGUAGE=AL32UTF8
set ODBCINI=/etc/odbc.ini
```

I have installed these packages:

```
postgresql-libs.x8664 - 8.4.20-8.el69
postgresql-odbc.x8664 - 08.04.0200-1.el6
unixODBC.x8664 - 2.2.14-14.el6
unixODBC-devel.x86_64 - 2.2.14-14.el6
```

Please help me.. I need to have the correct data in Oracle..
Thank you very much

Comment: Try using [oracle_fdw](https://github.com/laurenz/oracle_fdw). That should do the job.

Comment: `AL32UTF8` is the Oracle name for `UTF-8` - it is the same!

Comment: I think everything is fine, just your `isql` does not display data correct. You need to set `NLS_LANG` properly, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33783902/odbcconnection-returning-chinese-characters-as/33790600#33790600

Comment: I found a temporary solution, I just added convert('column_name','EE8ISO8859P2') for each column containing text. At the moment, all special characters are displaying correctly.