# Oracle sqlplus Chinese characters garbled

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

1. I run a simple query with oracle database 11g on CentOS, but I got wrong CHARACTER SET.

```
SQL> select col_name from table_name where rownum <= 1;

col_name 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
¸ñ귎Ϊʯҩ¼¯΅mRNAт¹ےࠃ萮Ŀ802³µ¼乄լ¾»»¯ůͨ¹¤³̡£
```

2. I get database CHARACTER SET as follows

```
SQL> select userenv('language') from dual;

USERENV('LANGUAGE')
----------------------------------------------------
AMERICAN_AMERICA.ZHS16GBK
```

3. Set CHARACTER SET to client
   `echo 'export NLS_LANG="AMERICAN_AMERICA.ZHS16GBK"'>>/etc/profile && source /etc/profile`
4. rerun query SQL, but also got problem, How can I resolve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your terminal settings with `locale charmap` or `echo $LANG` and verify if it matches with `ZHS16GBK`.

It is not required to use the same character set as your database. Using `NLS_LANG=AMERICAN_AMERICA.AL32UTF8` and UTF-8 in your terminal will also work. It is important that `NLS_LANG` matches your terminal character set.

See also [OdbcConnection returning Chinese Characters as "?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33783902/odbcconnection-returning-chinese-characters-as/33790600#33790600)

Comment: It works perfect when I set `export NLS_LANG="AMERICAN_AMERICA.AL32UTF8"
export LANG="zh_CN.UTF-8"` on my terminal