# Oracle -> Azure sql. Problem with encoding

Tags: oracle, azure-sql-database

I've created db link to make connection between oracle and azure sql. When i  run query

```
SELECT
'text',
a.c5,
d.c6
from tab1@db_link_azure a
 left join tab2@db_link_azure  b
   on a.c1 = b.c2
 left join tab3@db_link_azure c
   on c.c3= b.c4
 left join tab4@db_link_azure d
   on a.c5= d.c6
```

It works fine. But when i'm adding new column to select statment

```
SELECT
  'text',
   a.c5,
   d.c6,
   a.c10
from 
   tab1@db_link_azure a
   left join tab2@db_link_azure  b on a.c1 = b.c2
   left join tab3@db_link_azure c on c.c3= b.c4
   left join tab4@db_link_azure d on a.c5= d.c6
```

column d.c6 returns chinese characters -

```
㔸㈱㌹愱摢敡愸㔰㥤捥搸攷㑢㤶ㄹ㝡
㔸㈱㌹愱摢敡愸㔰㥤捥搸攷㑢㤶ㄹ㝡
```

Do you have any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

- The problem you're facing with the column **d.c6** returning Chinese characters may be due to differences in how characters are stored and interpreted between your Oracle and Azure SQL databases.
- This could be caused by settings related to how the databases handle character encoding and representation.
- Make sure to check the settings on your terminal by running the command `locale charmap` or `echo $LANG` to confirm if they are set to `ZHS16GBK`.

This will help you verify if the character encoding matches the one that is causing the issue.

You don't necessarily need to use the exact same character set as your database.
Using `NLS_LANG=AMERICAN_AMERICA.AL32UTF8` and `UTF-8` in your terminal should also be effective.
The key is to ensure that the `NLS_LANG` setting matches the character set in your terminal.

Also try with below too

```
HS_LANGUAGE=AMERICAN_AMERICA.ZHS16GBK
```

or

```
HS_LANGUAGE=CHINESE_CHINA.ZHS16GBK

HS_LANGUAGE=AMERICAN_AMERICA.ZHS16GBK
```

and commenting out

```
#HS_FDS_REMOTE_DB_CHARSET = ZHS16GBK
```

**Reference:** [Oracle connect to SQL Server Chinese character becomes question mark](https://forums.oracle.com/ords/apexds/post/oracle-connect-to-sql-server-chinese-character-becomes-ques-0068)

[ORACLE SQLPLUS CHINESE CHARACTERS GARBLED-ORACLE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72150089/oracle-sqlplus-chinese-characters-garbled)