# Set charset to UTF-8 in SQL*Plus

Tags: oracle, utf-8, sqlplus

I have a SQL script that contains the following statement:

`insert into employee(fname,lname) values('Jörg','Müller');`

My Database Charset ist set to AL32UTF8 but when I execute the script in SQL*Plus the german letters Ö and Ü are not saved correctly. How can I set the Charset of SQL*Plus to UTF-8?

Is it possible to set the SQL*Plus Charset to UTF-8 in my script file (the sql script file contains the command to set the charset to UTF-8)?

My runtime environment is Window but script should also be able to run on unix. My oracle version is 19c.

Comment: if you're using say, Windows terminal CMD prompt, you need to make sure windows encoding is ALSO set to Unicode - please describe your runtime environment and also version of Oracle

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SQL*Plus inherits the character set from `cmd` window. You need to set encoding to UTF-8 and tell it Oracle. This is done by `NLS_LANG` parameter.

Try this:

```
chcp 65001
set NLS_LANG=.AL32UTF8
sqlplus ....
```

Of course, this works only if your sql-file is also saved as UTF-8. Otherwise you need to adapt character sets from above.

See [OdbcConnection returning Chinese Characters as "?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33783902/odbcconnection-returning-chinese-characters-as/33790600#33790600)

Answer (score -1):

You would typically use the environment variable NLS_LANG and for example set it like this in windows: SET NLS_LANG=AMERICAN_AMERICA.AL32UTF8

Comment: Setting only `NLS_LANG` does not have any effect for SQLplus

Comment: In your question you explicitly wrote that you want utf8 encoding, but is your  source file utf8 encoded? Generally speaking the encoding of your source file encoding must match the nls_lang encoding.

Comment: Correct, as long as you run only an existing SQL-File and don't run any manual `INSERT` command, the terminal codepage does not matter.