# Set charset to UTF-8 in SQL Developer

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Using SQL Plus a was able to export data into UTF-8 format as described in [Set charset to UTF-8 in SQL*Plus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72205389/set-charset-to-utf-8-in-sqlplus)
However i need to do this in sql developer as well ?

The idea is to export it like in sql plus with the script not via GUI

@"c\sqlexp\spool_files\export.sql"

How does this looks like is ->

in CMD WIN10 i have set

```
chcp 65001
set NLS_LANG=.AL32UTF8
```

then i called scripts to first set parameters

```
-- disable output on terminal
set term off
set termout off
--set date format that import with FW033 is possible
alter session set NLS_DATE_FORMAT='DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI:SS';
-- suppress showing sql in result set
set echo off
-- only one header row
set pagesize 0
-- dont display the executed command
set verify off
-- eliminate row count message
set feedback off
-- make line long enough to hold data
set linesize 32767
-- eliminate trailing blanks
set trimspool on
-- eliminate not needed line breaks
clear breaks;
-- enable script name info
set appinfo on
set underline off
set colsep ';'
```

and then export with spool

```
@c:\sqlexp\data\RD.sql

spool c:\RD_OUTPUT.sql
    select
    'RD.ID'||';'
    ||'CODE'||';'
    from dual;
    select
    LTRIM(ID)||';'
    ||LTRIM(CODE)||';'
    from RD_AC_ACTION;
    spool off
```

-> Result with SQL PLUS File in UTF-8 all ok.

If i run this in SQL Developer ->  i got ??????? instead of for example ö

Answer (score 4):

Just use SPOOL. Ensure that
Preferences - Environment - Encoding is set to UTF-8.

```
cd c:\users\jdsmith\desktop
spool beer_emoji.txt
select 'it is  time' from dual;
spool off
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I edited the question -> the idea is to export it like in sql plus with the script not via GUI

@"c\sqlexp\spool_files\export.sql"

Comment: then edit your question and show how how you're 'exporting' your data in sqlplus, as sqlplus has no export command. It does have a SPOOL...