# DB query with unicode characters dosen't return value from python code

Tags: python, oracle, unicode, cx-oracle, python-unicode

A DB query dosen't return value from python code, but it returns on Oracle Developer console.

The chinese parameter is the reason. Can you help encode it from python ?

The N char didn't work with me. It still returns empty result.

The query : **`SELECT COUNT(*) OVER() CNT,  aid FROM rd_c_t_xl b WHERE name =N'根砧木'`**

I use python 3.9, and Cx_Oracle 8.3 and pandas.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `NLS_LANG` environment variable accordingly, most likely `NLS_LANG=.AL32UTF8`.

SQL Developer is Java/JDBC based, it does not use the `NLS_LANG` settings, that's the reason why it works.

See also [OdbcConnection returning Chinese Characters as "?"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33783902/odbcconnection-returning-chinese-characters-as/33790600#33790600)

Comment: didn't work with me.

Comment: Which encoding do you use in python?

Comment: I used UTF-8 and UTF-16 and both didn't work.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit the encoding in NLS_LANG hasn't been used since cx_Oracle 7.  The encoding defaults to UTF-8 and can only be overridden at connection.  And more recently in python-oracledb (the latest, renamed cx_Oracle) only UTF-8 can be used.