# Identifying bad rows(utf-8) in oracle table

Tags: oracle

I get the below error message when trying to export and Oracle table using ora2pg. I would like to know if there is a query i can run to find out which columns have this utf-8 characters in it?

Unicode surrogate U+DBC0 is illegal in UTF-8 at /usr/lib64/perl5/IO/Handle.pm line 420.721 (1800 recs/sec)
Unicode surrogate U+DF72 is illegal in UTF-8 at /usr/lib64/perl5/IO/Handle.pm line 420.
Unicode surrogate U+DBC0 is illegal in UTF-8 at /usr/lib64/perl5/IO/Handle.pm line 420.
Unicode surrogate U+DF72 is illegal in UTF-8 at /usr/lib64/perl5/IO/Handle.pm line 420.
Unicode surrogate U+DBC0 is illegal in UTF-8 at /usr/lib64/perl5/IO/Handle.pm line 420.721 (1802 recs/sec)

Thanks.

Comment: I think the actual problem is a wrong setting of `NLS_LANG` parameter. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33783902/odbcconnection-returning-chinese-characters-as/33790600#33790600

Comment: Current encoding settings:
Oracle NLS_LANG AMERICAN_AMERICA.AL32UTF8
Oracle NLS_NCHAR AL32UTF8

Comment: `NLS_NCHAR AL32UTF8`  is very unlikely. As written, you set `AL32UTF8` in your `NLS_LANG` but your (perl?) script is not UTF-8 - that could be the problem.