# Oracle, displaying special characters

Tags: oracle, character-encoding

In one of our tables, we have a column which indicates some currency scale.  Some of the values are like $ or % or #......but, there is one record with a cents sign:  ¢

Issue we're having is that when we query it from SqlPlus, it shows as a question mark.   And, when the application, written in PHP retrieves it, it is also a question mark.

Is there a way to get this to be returned at a cents sign:  ¢

Many thanks!

Comment: Are you sure this is a problem with retrieving data and not a problem with inserting the data? If the data has been inserted with the wrong character set and is not stored correctly then it does not matter what you do to try to retrieve it. What output do you get when you use `SELECT column_name, DUMP(column_name) FROM table_name`?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33783902/odbcconnection-returning-chinese-characters-as/33790600#33790600

Comment: Where do you start sqlplus? Windows or Linux?

Comment: [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f2f900/1) is an example of where the `INSERT` goes wrong; once you get to that point you have invalid data and you need to fix the data itself rather than trying to fix how you are retrieving it.

Comment: The data is correct in the table.   If I look in Toad I can see the cents symbol.   I tried changing my NLS to unicode, and then it gave me:   Â¢      So, getting closer.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [Encoding Suport](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00A2/charset_support.htm) and [Codepage Support](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00A2/codepage_support.htm) it should be no problem.

Most likely there is only mismatch between `NLS_LANG` settings and your actual codepage used by SQL*plus.

SQL*plus inherits the codepage from calling `cmd` window. Interrogate or set the codepage and set `NLS_LANG` accordingly, for example like this:

```
chcp 1252
set NLS_LANG=.WE8MSWIN1252
sqlplus ...
```

If you work with Linux, then interrogate encoding of your terminal with `locale charmap` or `echo $LANG`