# Oracle spool encoding output

Tags: oracle, encoding, spool

Here is a test case:

```
create table mydatabase.samuel(toto varchar(10));
insert into mydatabase.samuel values('¿¿)');
select toto, dump(toto) from mydatabase.samuel;
```

and the ouput is : `¿¿) Typ=1 Len=5: 194,191,194,191,41`

When I try to export this result to a file I do the following:

```
set TERMOUT OFF
set timing off
set pagesize 0
set colsep ';'
set feedback off
set linesize 1000
set trimspool on
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_LANGUAGE='FRENCH';
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_TERRITORY='FRANCE';
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_CURRENCY='€';
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_ISO_CURRENCY='FRANCE';
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS=', ';
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_CALENDAR='GREGORIAN';
ALTER SESSION SET nls_date_format='dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss';
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE='FRENCH';
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_CHARACTERSET='AL32UTF8';
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_SORT='FRENCH';
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_TIME_FORMAT='HH24:MI:SSXFF';
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT='DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SSXFF';
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_TIME_TZ_FORMAT='HH24:MI:SSXFF TZR';
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_TIMESTAMP_TZ_FORMAT='DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SSXFF TZR';
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DUAL_CURRENCY='€';
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET='AL16UTF16';
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_COMP='BINARY';
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS='BYTE';
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_NCHAR_CONV_EXCP='FALSE';
spool /mydir/myfile.csv
SELECT toto || ';' || dump(toto) FROM mydatabase.samuel;
spool off;
exit
```

I got the NLS values by doing `SELECT * FROM V$NLS_PARAMETERS;`

And the result is `??);Typ=1 Len=5: 194,191,194,191,41` despite the `NLS_CHARACTERSET='AL32UTF8'`.

How can I fix the encoding of the export?

Comment: 194,191 is U+00BF which is 'inverted question mark' and 41 is U+0029 which is 'right' parenthesis , which is what you are providing. You're getting the same result from both queries... so I'm not sure what you're asking. What are you expecting to see? The inverted question mark is often shown as a placeholder for something that can't be displayed - but you're using it explicitly here. You may be asking the wrong question. More generally, check `nls_session_parameters` and your operating system, shell and client settings (e.g. NLS_LANG in the shell).

Comment: `¿¿)` is translated to `??)` in the output file, which I don't want

Comment: Is it - or is that how your text editor is displaying it? Again, look at the encoding/character set outside the database as well.

Comment: My text editor reads the file as UTF-8, which seems right to me.

Comment: Doing `od -An -vtu1 myfile.csv`, I get `63  63  41  10`, so it is not a question of display.

Comment: And what about OS/shell - you haven't said which client you're using; if SQL\*Plus then what is your NLS_LANG set to, if SQL Developer then what is its encoding set to, etc.? (It might also be a good idea to add clarifying information to the question itself, not just as comments.)

Comment: It's indeed a problem related to the client environment, testing here: in SQL/Plus I get ??, sqlcl: ¿¿, SQLDeveloper: ¿¿, all three run on the same machine, and in web SQL worksheet also ¿¿. (And echo host $NLS_LANG is empty in both SQL/Plus and sqlcl... being a Java tool, most probably sqlcl doesn't use it), so eventually to make SQL/Plus returning the correct result at least here: "export NLS_LANG=American_America.UTF8" in command line before launching SQL/Plus. (adapt syntax to your shell if needed)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33783902/odbcconnection-returning-chinese-characters-as/33790600#33790600

Comment: Thanks to everybody, changing NLS_LANG on the client side worked.