# Cyrillic characters are not displayed correctly in XML on Oracle

Tags: xml, oracle, plsql, utf-8

I have DB Oracle 19c.

NLS:

| PARAMETER | VALUE |
| --- | --- |
| NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET | AL16UTF16 |
| NLS_CHARACTERSET | AL32UTF8 |

Сreate a XML:

```
SELECT xmlroot(xmlagg(xmlelement("MA",
                                 xmlforest(1 "STATUS",
                                           v.app_type "APP_TYPE",
                                           v.fname "FNAME",
                                           v.pname "PNAME",
                                           v.lname "LNAME",
                                           v.dob "DOB",
                                           v.dob_od "DOB_OD",
                                           v.pob "POB",
                                           v.inc_tm "INC_TM",
                                           v.gender "GENDER",
                                           v.educ_lvl "EDUC_LVL",
                                           v.marit_st "MARIT_ST",
                                           v.kids "KIDS"))),
               version '1.0" encoding="UTF-8') AS xml
FROM nh_data_vector v
WHERE v.id_nh = 1
```

The XML is created and displayed correctly.

If I use xmlserialize and make blob, then сyrillic characters break.

```
SELECT xmlserialize(document xmlroot(xmlagg(xmlelement("MA",
                                              xmlforest(1 "STATUS",
                                                        v.app_type "APP_TYPE",
                                                        v.fname "FNAME",
                                                        v.pname "PNAME",
                                                        v.lname "LNAME",
                                                        v.dob "DOB",
                                                        v.dob_od "DOB_OD",
                                                        v.pob "POB",
                                                        v.inc_tm "INC_TM",
                                                        v.gender "GENDER",
                                                        v.educ_lvl "EDUC_LVL",
                                                        v.marit_st "MARIT_ST",
                                                        v.kids "KIDS"))),
                            version '1.0" encoding="UTF-8') AS BLOB encoding 'UTF-8'
                    version '1.0') AS xml
FROM nh_data_vector v
WHERE v.id_nh = 1
```

```
<MA>
    <STATUS>1</STATUS>
    <APP_TYPE>4</APP_TYPE>
    <FNAME>Р”РњР˜РўР Р˜Р™</FNAME>
    <PNAME>Р’Р›РђР”Р˜РњР˜Р РћР’Р˜Р§</PNAME>
    <LNAME>Р—Р˜РњР˜Рќ</LNAME>
    <DOB>1991-11-20</DOB>
    <DOB_OD>1991-11-20</DOB_OD>
    <POB>Р“РћР .РЎРђР РђРўРћР’</POB>
    <INC_TM>100000</INC_TM>
    <GENDER>1</GENDER>
    <EDUC_LVL>3</EDUC_LVL>
    <MARIT_ST>1</MARIT_ST>
    <KIDS>0</KIDS>
</MA>
```

Use decoder online and I saw that the encoding Windows-1251. But how do I get this encoding? I need to use UTF-8.

I'm using `convert()`, but it did not help.

Comment: You face an unusual [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) case (*example in Python for its universal intelligibility*): `'ДМИТРИЙ ВЛАДИМИРОВИЧ ЗИМИН'.encode( 'utf-8').decode( 'cp1251', 'backslashreplace').replace( '\\x98', '˜')` returns `'Р”РњР˜РўР\xa0Р˜Р™ Р’Р›РђР”Р˜РњР˜Р\xa0РћР’Р˜Р§ Р—Р˜РњР˜Рќ'`. Note that `\xa0` in result is ``` ``` (U+00A0,  *No-Break Space*), and  '\x98' isn't defined in `cp1251`. No clue where that `˜` (U+02DC,  *Small Tilde*) comes from…

Answer (score 0):

The database `NLS_CHARACTERSET` is just one part. You also need to tell the database which character set is used by your **client**. Unless you have a Java/JDBC based client, this is usually done by environment variable `NLS_LANG`.

See [OdbcConnection returning Chinese Characters as "?"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33783902/odbcconnection-returning-chinese-characters-as/33790600#33790600)