# Oracle client encoding

Tags: oracle, encoding, plsqldeveloper

I am trying to make development environment on other pc. Installed oracle client 19, PL/SQL Developer.

Here is nls_parameters from server:

[image]

Accordingly i set `NLS_LANG` on client in registry:

[image]

But, i still get nonsense in PL/SQL Developer:

[image]

And in sqlplus:

```
SQL> select * from adm_org;

    ORG_ID
----------
ORG_NAME
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ORG_FULL_NAME
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
         1
─σ≡µαΓφΦΘ ßε≡π
╙∩≡αΓδ│φφ  Σσ≡µαΓφΦ∞ ßε≡πε∞

         2
╠╘╬ ≥α ╠╥─
╙∩≡αΓδ│φφ  ╠╘╬ ≥α Ωεε≡ΣΦφα÷│  ╠╥─
```

Then i tried this with SQL Developer and it was a successful. But SQL Developer uses separate client to connect to Oracle. It seems that it uses Cp1252. [Supported character sets](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/nlspg/appendix-A-locale-data.html) only have WE8MSWIN1252 and it didn't fixed the problem.

What am i missing? Character set supposed to be the same on client and server? I have never had such problems before, everything was fixed by setting NLS_LANG.

Comment: Can you retry by setting `NLS_LANG` to `UKRAINIAN_UKRAINE.CL8ISO8859P5` within the registry. Btw, I presume `NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS` should be set to `,.` or `.,` ( but not `,` only ), and `NLS_SORT` to `UKRAINIAN` .... Shouldn't they ?

Comment: I tried `NLS_LANG = UKRAINIAN_UKRAINE.CL8ISO8859P5`, still gibberish but different kind. `NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS` is set to comma and space. And yes `NLS_SORT` should be set to `UKRAINIAN` and `NLS_LANGUAGE`... but i am not DBA, i don't have access.

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan `NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS` might be `", "` - which is the standard for Germany and Austria, for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL Developer is a Java/JDBC based client, it does not use `NLS_LANG` settings.

PL/SQL Developer I do not know, have a look at the settings.

`sqlplus` inherits characters set from command line. Try this

```
chcp 1251
SET NLS_LANG=.CL8MSWIN1251
sqlplus ...
```

It is not required to have the same character set on database and client (although it is a good idea to have them the same). Important part is that `NLS_LANG` value declares the real character set which is used by the client. And the client character set should support all characters which are supported by the database.

See also [OdbcConnection returning Chinese Characters as "?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33783902/odbcconnection-returning-chinese-characters-as/33790600#33790600)

Comment: Yes, this helps with `sqlplus`. I guess something wrong with `PL/SQL Developer`, will search about that on the Internet.