# Oracle NLS Settings Special Characters Replacement Handling

Tags: oracle, function, plsql, substr, nls-lang

I found a weird situation in Oracle

Situation Faced

- I used substr to split the character one by one and if the byte of length >= 2 then replace it with spacing.
- It work successfully in my session but it not work in the Oracle Job.
  I found that it would possibility that replace more characters like
  Aöasd
  It will return with value
  A sd

For my further testing, I think this is because the NLS Settings

- Database's NLS Settings = 'German.Germany.AL32UTF8'
- User's Session's NLS Settings = 'AMERICAN.AMERICA.AL32UTF8'

In German.Germany.AL32UTF8 the substr function unable to grab the correct character especially after the German Special Character. However it is work in User's Session

Besides that, I also had try to use regex_replace but it is also not work for the Oracle Job it unable to replace it.

string:= REGEXP_REPLACE(ps_string, '[äöüßÄÖÜ]', ' ');

Instead of changing on the NLS Settings is there have any other solution for this?

Comment: Most likely your `NLS_LANG` value (i.e. `AMERICAN.AMERICA.AL32UTF8`) does not match the character set which is used by your application (maybe SQLplus?). See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33783902/odbcconnection-returning-chinese-characters-as/33790600#33790600

Comment: "I had created a function with substr which used to replace all character that the byte of length >= 2" - what is the reason for that?

Comment: The purpose is to remove special character that length of byte >= 2 and I found that the substr unable to grab the data although I provided the correct position.  For example : AÜHLKÖ In German.Germany.AL32UTF8 substr('AÜHLKÖ',3,1) It had return L instead of H. I not sure why it unable to used substr to detect the characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is different character set in different database.

In my database with **NLS Settings = 'AMERICAN.AMERICA.AL32UTF8'**

```
WITH CTE AS (SELECT 'Aöasd' STR FROM DUAL)
SELECT SUBSTR(STR,LEVEL,1) AS NEW_ST, 
       LENGTHB(SUBSTR(STR,LEVEL,1)) AS NEW_ST_LB 
  FROM CTE
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= LENGTH(STR);

N  NEW_ST_LB
- ----------
A          1
ö          2
a          1
s          1
d          1
```

Now, I tried the same query in my other DB with German character set and result is 1 for all characters. (`WE8ISO8859P15`)

```
N  NEW_ST_LB
- ----------
A          1
ö          1 --<--- See this
a          1
s          1
d          1
```

The thing is in `WE8ISO8859P15` character set, It takes only 1 byte to store it rather then 2 Bytes.

### **Solution**:

Use the `CONVERT` function to convert each character to `UTF8` and then check the length of the character in terms of byte and replace it if it is greater than 1.

**Query:**

```
WITH CTE AS (SELECT 'Aöasd' STR FROM DUAL)
SELECT CONVERT(SUBSTR(STR,LEVEL,1), 'UTF8' ) AS NEW_ST, 
       LENGTHB( CONVERT(SUBSTR(STR,LEVEL,1), 'UTF8' )) AS NEW_ST_LB 
  FROM CTE
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= LENGTH(STR);
```

Result in DB with **NLS Settings = 'AMERICAN.AMERICA.AL32UTF8'**

```
NEW_ST                NEW_ST_LB
-------------------- ----------
A                             1
ö                             2
a                             1
s                             1
d                             1
```

Result in DB with **NLS Settings = 'German.Germany.AL32UTF8'**

```
NEW_S  NEW_ST_LB
----- ----------
A              1
Ã¶             2
a              1
s              1
d              1
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! The problem that I faced is I found that the substr function unable to grab the correct data.
For example : AÜHLKÖ
In German.Germany.AL32UTF8 
substr('AÜHLKÖ',3,1) 
It would return L instead of H. I not sure why it unable to used substr to detect the characters.

Comment: `WITH CTE AS (SELECT 'AÜHLKÖ' STR FROM DUAL)
SELECT CONVERT(SUBSTR(STR,LEVEL,1), 'UTF8' ) AS NEW_ST, 
       LENGTHB( CONVERT(SUBSTR(STR,LEVEL,1), 'UTF8' )) AS NEW_ST_LB FROM CTE
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= LENGTH(STR);` --> It returns correct characters using `substr` in German.Germany.AL32UTF8

Comment: Is this related to the Oracle Job's client charset as the Oracle Job's Client_CHARSET is WE8ISO8859P1 and it is not WE8MSWIN1252 ?

Comment: `SELECT
    PARAMETER,
    VALUE AS DATABASE_CHARACTERSET
  FROM
    NLS_DATABASE_PARAMETERS
 WHERE
    PARAMETER = 'NLS_CHARACTERSET';` --> `WE8ISO8859P15`

Answer (score 1):

I am quite sure "remove special character that length of byte >= 2" is more a dirty hack than a solution of your actual problem.

Anyway, when you set your `NLS_LANG` properly, i.e. that it matches the character set of your application, then it works well:

```
SELECT SUBSTR('AÜHLKÖ',3,1)
FROM DUAL;
   
SUBSTR('AÜHLKÖ',3,1)
--------------------
H
```

As an alternative try [SUBSTRC](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions196.htm#SQLRF06114)

If you really need to remove "special characters" - which I doubt - then this function should work:

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(ASCIISTR('ABÄCöE'), '\\[[:xdigit:]]{4}', ' ')
```