# SQL prompt line not visible

Tags: oracle

[image: command line image]

Does anyone know what's the reason it's displaying like this. It's running on a Windows 11 laptop. My other friends are also using Windows 11 but did not encounter this problem. Thanks in advance for the assist.

I tried reinstalling, i tried to check my system type which is 64 bit and install the compatible version.

Comment: To me, it looks like character set issue/mismatch. Have a look at what Wernfried said here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33783902/odbcconnection-returning-chinese-characters-as/33790600#33790600