How to set Oracle NLS_LANG on Windows?
I have a Windows machine and I'm trying to connect to remote Oracle 19 database.
Oracle is not installed in my machine. I have no oracle_home.
I need to set NLS_LANG to AMERICAN_AMERICA.UTF8 in my machine.
I created a registry entry in the following path :

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/SOFTWARE/ORACLE (I created this folder)
String entry: NLS_LANG with value AMERICAN_AMERICA.UTF8

But when connected to SQL developer, it doesn't show UTF8 characters.
How can I solve this?

What does it show - question marks, upside question marks, question marks in a box, something else? Check in Preferences->Environment that Encoding is set to UTF-8 (or at least something suitable), and in Preferences->Code Editor->Fonts that your selected font supports the characters you're having a problem with.

Here is what it shows : ��

SQL Developer is Java based and Java does not use NLS_LANG settings. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33783902/odbcconnection-returning-chinese-characters-as/33790600#33790600 for details

You may be misunderstanding the idea. The NLS_LANG variable must be the actual charset of your client (which is usually AL16UTF16 or WE8MSWIN1252 on Windows), and not the charset of the database.
The SQL*net layer does the conversion from the database charset (whichever it is) to the charset indicated in the variable.
If the database is UTF8 and you set your NLS_LANG to UTF8, no conversion will be done and the client will receive the "original" bitwise representation, which won't be right.

In general you are fully right, however JDBC does not utilize NLS_LANG settings. See https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/JJDBC/global.htm#JJDBC28643

Good point, but I don't know for sure that SQL developer always uses JDBC (part of the "Oracle thin client"). And the OP was specifically (probably mistakenly) asking about NLS_LANG. Also, if SQL developer is still Java based, there will be some conversion in the middle (as Java uses UTF16, as just as Windows, at least internally). The OP may also be just having a problem with the fonts used to render the characters. We would need more info to say.

The NLS_LANG for UTF8 is AL32UTF8. I don't know if you can set it within the registry entry you talk about but you can add NLS_LANG as a system environment variable inside in Windows. So that would be:
Variable: NLS_LANG
Value:    AMERICAN_AMERICA.AL32UTF8


Both options work, but the variable should have the character set of the client (and not that of the database). Anyway, as @Wernfried said, SQL developer may not be using the "classic" globalization support provided by SQL*net.
